# What is the best way to remove html tags from an html page?

Tags: java, html, html-parsing

What is the best way to remove html tags from an html page? I just want to have the actual text, and not the html tags. I store the text in a string without including the html tags. What is the simplest way to do this? An example page is shown below:

```
<HTML><HEAD>
<META NAME="Docdate" CONTENT="05/02/2011">
<META NAME="m_title" CONTENT="TWO SECURITY GUARDS HACKED TO DEATH DURING A FIGHT">
<META NAME="m_author" CONTENT="">
<TITLE>MALAYSIA NEWS -- GENERAL NEWS -- 05/02/2011 -- TWO SECURITY GUARDS HACKED TO DEATH DURING A FIGHT</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY BACKGROUND="#FFFFFF">
<PRE>
05/02/2011

POLICE-FIGHT

TWO SECURITY GUARDS HACKED TO DEATH DURING A FIGHT





    KUALA LUMPUR, Feb 5 (Bernama) -- Two security guards were hacked to death in

a fight that broke out at Damansara Perdana construction site last night. 

    Both men, aged 20 and 26, were found dead at the scene with slash wounds on

their bodies in the 8.20pm incident. 

    Petaling Jaya OCPD ACP Arjunaidi Mohammed said the fight started following

an argument involving a security guard and several foreign workers at the site. 

    "One of them had an argument with several of the workers. He then called two

of his friends who are also security guards but working in other areas. 

    "A group of 12 to 15 foreign workers, carrying sharp weapons, then attacked

them," he told reporters at the scene today. 

    The other security guard managed to flee to safety, he added. 

    "The foreign workers had also left the area. We have picked up a security

guard in the area and two Indonesian workers to have their statements taken," he

said, adding that a manhunt was underway for the suspects. 

    -- BERNAMA 

    NMR AKT JS





</PRE>
<BODY></HTML>
```

Comment: Have you had a look at jsoup?

Comment: Assume a spherical cow. Also, assume the page is stored in a `String` called `str`. Assume that you know how to use regex. Now, use `str.replaceAll()` to remove all html tags (If you don't know, it is `str.replaceAll("\\<.*\\>","")`. Note this just removes all data encased in <>'s)

Comment: Don't try to use regular expressions for this.  It will go horribly wrong.

Comment: @Quincunx This is a very bad idea.

Comment: @user2310289 I know, but that is probably the best you can easily get with regex. I definitely recommend not using regex.

Comment: Hi @David Wallace , can you tell what's the disadvantage of using regx in this type ?

Comment: @SeeTheC - I would like to answer that, truly; but many people have answered it already on this site, and far more eloquently than I ever could.  Have a read of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/7564061#7564061 and of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not, then ask me again if you still have questions.

Answer (score 0):

Use a library like [jsoup](http://jsoup.org) to parse the HTML, then traverse the DOM that is produced and output the text nodes.  Real HTML in the "wild" is often extremely malformed, so trying to do this reliably yourself is going to be huge wasted effort.  Better to use a library that is already designed to handle malformed HTML.